# Can we cache a value until it is updated in the database?

Tags: python, database, caching

Is there any caching library for Python (or general technique) that can cache a database query result until the underlying tables of the query have been updated?

The cache should never output stale values. At the same time, the application should only need to query the database once for each change in the data.

I want to optimize a Flask app. I am facing this issue a lot with pages that have a list of objects that change infrequently. It is detrimental to present stale data, so a time-based cache cannot be used.

Right now there are hundreds of queries per hour due to multiple users accessing these pages. I would like to reduce that to the absolute minimum (i.e. only when there is an update to the data), and keep the data cached in-memory.

**A possible approach** would be to maintain `last_updated` timestamps for each table somewhere (possibly Redis) and check these before querying the database.

Comment: Check out something like Redis or Memcached. You just have to ensure that the cache is always updated whenever you update the DB.

Comment: Yes, but I want a library / ORM feature that does this without having to implement the whole architecture from scratch, if possible.

Comment: Library recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.